# Remove a unnecessary file after git commit and push

Tags: git

I did a commit and pushed the commit directly to the feature branch. One of the files in the commit was not required and I need to revert the single file from commit.

I tried,  git reset HEAD^1 file-path
and also tried,  git checkout HEAD^ -- file-path
to remove the file.

When I try to amend, the status is feature branch and local has diverged and they have 1 different commit each.

Help on how to commit after removing the file from commit.

Will git push -f work? But in my environment push force is disabled.

I have submodule service.

On git status, it showed - service(new commits)
It contains,
+Subproject commit commit-id
-Subproject commit commit-id

In my commit by mistake this was included and pushed to branch. Is there a way to remove it.

Comment: Why cant you just delete the file and commit it again. It would have been simpler. But ofcourse if that file you commited is a credential file then its a different story

Comment: I can't delete the file. There's actually a submodule named service. So the file I accidently pushed is,  named service and shows 2 commit SHA as insert and delete. The branch is used by others and I pushed directly to the branch.

Comment: But you can `git rm -f --cached that_file` and commit. This will leave your file in the worktree, but remove it from the commit.

Comment: The file shows Subproject commit. I cannot do git rm because it will delete my subproject or submodule named service.

Comment: `force pushing` might be a candidate here.  revert to the commit back right before the accidental file push, then force push.  *WARNING*: this would delete any subsequent commits even made by others

Answer (score 0):

You can revert only one file to a specified revision.

First you can check on which commits the file was changed.

git log path/to/file.txt

Then you can checkout the file with the revision number.

git checkout 4cdc61015724f9965575ba954c8cd4232c8b42e4 /path/to/file.txt

After that you can commit and push it again.